# Can't Remove "style" attribute from HTML

Tags: c#, regex

Trying to remove all attributes except "src" from all html doms. like img or iframe.

Im using regex to do, but doesnt work;

```
    inp = Regex.Replace(inp, @"(<\s*[a-z][a-z0-9]*.*\s)(style\s*=\s*"".*?"")([^<>]*>)", "$1 $3", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

What's the problem that I cant see?

Comment: this: `(style\s*=\s*"".*?"")` should be something like this: `(style\s*=\s*".*")`

Comment: The problem that you can't see is that you do not use proper HTML parser, but Regex instead. [Regex shouldn't be used to parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3005263)

Comment: Examples of input, expected output - where are they?

Comment: According to [this example](http://ideone.com/kazEl6) it works.

Answer (score 0):

My proposition would be:

Wouldn't it be simplier to find all html tags with pattern `"<[^>]+>"`, having that just remove all that doesn't contain the string `"src"`?